# Loop through html object collection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-events

How can I access the html element div.card as shown below, the div returns as Proxy{}  in lightning and I cannot manipulate the DOM. The div comes from the content in controller because it is in rich text format, so I had to use lighting formattedText. Is there a way to access it in lightning? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you use:

```
for(var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++) {
  // do something here
}
```

Because HTMLCollection is not a list, you can't use the more familiar `for(var x in y)` syntax.

Comment: hi sfdcfox, I've tried that it doesn't work either.